# Get specific column with Get-AzureADUser

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I need something like the command `Get-AzureADUser`, but getting only `DisplayName` column, not the others (`ObjectID`, `UserPrincipalName`, `UserType`).

Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to see one, or a specific set of columns when running a PowerShell command, use the "Select-Object" command to select the columns, e.g.

```
Get-AzureADUser | select DisplayName
```

to select just one column, or

```
Get-AzureADUser | select DisplayName,ObjectId
```

to display multiple